# How prove $f(x)$ is derived function on domain,if $x^x=y^y$

Tags: analysis

let $p,q>0$,and such $$p\ln{p}=q\ln{q},p<q$$
let
$$q=f(p)$$

prove that :$f(x)$ is  derived function on domain

This problem I can consider Lambert W function  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function
since
$$p^p=q^q$$.
then if $q=f(p)$,
then first we must know this $p\in ( )?$ Thank you

But I can't,Thank you

Comment: While I don't understand the question, the function $g(x)=x^x$, restricted to positive $x$, is two-to-one for $g\le 1$ and one-to-one for $g>1$.  The first equation is equivalent to $p^p=q^q$.

Comment: Thank you,I think we must determine this $f(x)$ domain $x\in ( )?$

Comment: I think !vadim just specified the domain as $x\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F(x,y)=x^x+y^y$,$x>0,y>0$. We just need to prove $F(x,y)=0$ determines a function $y=f(x)$, and $x,y$ satisfying $F_y(x,y)\neq0$(I note it as $\Omega$).It is easy to show $F$ is differentiable. So from the implicit function theory, we can see $y=f(x)$ is differentiable in domain $\Omega$.